# setOnItemSelectedListener not being called?

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I'm new to Android and was working on my first app. I was trying to parse the contents of a Google Sheets spreadsheets, specifically a list of names into a `Spinner`. I've done so successfully by using an `ArrayAdapter` with an `ArrayList` as I can see the options when I expand the `Spinner`. The problem I'm facing is that the `Spinner` doesn't show the currently selected item when one is selected. If you try to run my code, you'll see that if you try to click the submit `Button`, it'll tell you that `null` is being selected, so I've narrowed down my problem to the currently selected name String not being selected.

Here is my **MainActivity class:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

Spinner spBusinessType;
Button btnsubmit;

ArrayAdapter<String> adapterBusinessType;

String sbusinesstype;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    spBusinessType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spBussinessType);

    btnsubmit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
    btnsubmit.setOnClickListener(this);

    new DownloadWebpageTask(new AsyncResult() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(JSONObject object) {
            processJson(object);
        }
    }).execute("https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=1JKU2Vt_gMNUYYALct4m9xElLdpGlQ3N4uhS9qFRzxOQ");

    adapterBusinessType = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, names);
    adapterBusinessType.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spBusinessType.setAdapter(adapterBusinessType);

    spBusinessType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v,
                                   int position, long id) {
            // On selecting a spinner item
            sbusinesstype = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            System.out.println(sbusinesstype);

            // Showing selected spinner item
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Bussiness Type : " + sbusinesstype, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have selected " + sbusinesstype,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void processJson(JSONObject object) {

    try {
        JSONArray rows = object.getJSONArray("rows");

        for (int r = 0; r < rows.length(); ++r) {
            JSONObject row = rows.getJSONObject(r);
            JSONArray columns = row.getJSONArray("c");

            String name = columns.getJSONObject(0).getString("v");
            names.add(name);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

the **AsyncResult interface** I'm using to obtain a `JSON` object from Google Sheets:

```
public interface AsyncResult
{
    void onResult(JSONObject object);
}
```

the **DownloadWebpageTask class** that is obtaining and parsing the JSON object:

```
public class DownloadWebpageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
AsyncResult callback;

public DownloadWebpageTask(AsyncResult callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

    // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
    try {
        return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return "Unable to download the requested page.";
    }
}

// onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // remove the unnecessary parts from the response and construct a JSON
    int start = result.indexOf("{", result.indexOf("{") + 1);
    int end = result.lastIndexOf("}");
    String jsonResponse = result.substring(start, end);
    try {
        JSONObject table = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
        callback.onResult(table);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private String downloadUrl(String urlString) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        // Starts the query
        conn.connect();
        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        is = conn.getInputStream();

        String contentAsString = convertStreamToString(is);
        return contentAsString;
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            is.close();
        }
    }
}

private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

the **activity_main** layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the **content_main** layout file that I put the Spinner in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Select Business Type"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spBussinessType"
    style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Spinner>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/submit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="Submit"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

What is causing the adapter to not detect when one of the name strings is being selected? Could it be related to how I'm parsing them from the Google Sheet?

Comment: show stacktrace for any errors.

Comment: Unrelated: Why don't you actually parse the JSON instead of substring-ing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didnt notify the ArrayAdapter that the data has changed, you originally passed empty Arraylist and upon filling the array list, you have to notifiy the Adapter that data has changed and its time for it to consider that, something like

```
private void processJson(JSONObject object) {
    try {
        JSONArray rows = object.getJSONArray("rows");

        for (int r = 0; r < rows.length(); ++r) {
            JSONObject row = rows.getJSONObject(r);
            JSONArray columns = row.getJSONArray("c");

            String name = columns.getJSONObject(0).getString("v");
            names.add(name);
        }
        adapterBusinessType.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

That should help.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear no data is being displayed in your Adapter. Nothing can be selected. Your listener code looks fine.

Put `adapterBusinessType.notifyDatasetChanged()` into the processJson method. Outside the catch or after you add all the data to the list.

Or... replace `names.add` with `adapterBusinessType.add`